# PHP exact search

Tags: php, search

So I have

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$f = fopen("address.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
   if (strstr($line, $q)) {
       print "<li>found: $line";
```

Lets say I have

```
Street 1 number 122
Street 2 number 22
```

in `address.txt` and I want to search for the number `22`.

How to search for `22`, but not to get `122` also?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some example text from address.txt ..what is their format

Comment: Every on new line

Street 1 number 122
Street 2 number 22
Street 3 number 65

Comment: a naive solution would be to surround `$q` with spaces: `if(strstr($line, ' ' . $q . ' '))`

Comment: Steve, like that I don't have any result

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a database for this? (Text) files are so much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to accomplish this. Quick example:

```
if(preg_match('/\b22\b/', $line)) {
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/817207
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/y9slbd/1/

Example using input (the `$q`):

```
if(preg_match('/\b' . preg_quote($q, '/') . \b/', $line)) {
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

(Although your example of `22` shouldn't have caused any issues if concatenated into this example)

Comment: I wonder what happened to that comment the OP left here earlier, the one which said that worked. They also failed to respond to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567676/php-exact-search#comment76124262_44567676) I left them earlier.

Comment: My example and the test with 22, so I was thinking it is working...
I need to use form in order to say what I am looking for

Comment: You can pass `$q` safely to the regex with http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php.